# How do I determine which render pipeline I'm using in an existing Unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, renderer

I have an existing project and just found out there are multiple render pipelines available. I don't remember which I chose (if I chose) back when creating the project. How do I determine which render pipeline I'm using in an existing Unity project?

https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/render-pipelines.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Graphics` 
[image]

If you chose the Built-in Render Pipeline (default) the Scriptable Render Pipeline Settings field will say None.